# Radiobuttons, how to replace all those if statements

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

Several places in my program, the RadioButton matching the selected item has to be checked, and I have a lot of if statements like so:

```
DataRowView TempRow = (DataRowView)ScheduleDataGrid.SelectedItem;

if (Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]) == "Bio1")
{
    BioRB1.IsChecked = true;
}
if (Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]) == "Bio2")
{
    BioRB2.IsChecked = true;
}
if (Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]) == "Bio3")
```

and so on... I want to replace all this with something short and smart.
I tried using the number of the bio to relate to the button like so:

```
string bioselected = Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]);

int i = Convert.ToInt16(bioselected.Substring(bioselected.Length - 1, 1));

BioRB[i].IsChecked = true;
```

but doing a BioRB[i] doesn't work, it ignores the [i] and says BioRB does not exist. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What UI framework? ASP? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: and it's a WPF application

Comment: you can use  the next expresion BioRB[i].IsCheched=i.equals("Bio") ? true:false;

Comment: If you group your radio buttons on a panel, I believe you can just loop through those controls. In VB, sorry:

      For each rbtn as RadioButton in [Panel].Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
        [insert your conditions here]
      Next

Without seeing the properties of your buttons, it's hard to say why you aren't getting the expected outcome. From what I can see, you have a (bound?) `DataGridView` and the user clicks on a row. Then you create a temp row? Why not use the `CellContentClick` event handler instead?

Comment: Are you creating a List<RadioButton> or something?  If you are only wanting your code to "look" better you could use a swich statement.  As far as the other approach you were going for..none of that is going to give you better performance so I would just comment your code really well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BioRB[i]` is not doing anything like what you think it's doing.  All variable references (controls included) have to be well-defined at compile time - you can't refer to a control's name by building a string that matches the name.**

Try creating a list of your radio buttons.  Then you can index into the list:

```
List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>()
{
    BioRB1,
    BioRB2
};

string bioselected = Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]);
int i = Convert.ToInt16(bioselected.Substring(bioselected.Length - 1, 1));
radioButtons[i].IsChecked = true;
```

** Technically you can do this via reflection, but it's far more complex than what you've tried.

Comment: @humudu You're welcome, but on SO, "thanks" posts are discouraged.  If you found this helpful, consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer instead.

Comment: @BJMyers this is what I thought he wanted but I wasn't sure...plus one for using List<RadioButton>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will look better:

```
string caseSwitch = Convert.ToString(TempRow["Bio"]);
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "Bio1":
        BioRB1.IsChecked = true;
        break;
    case "Bio2":
        BioRB2.IsChecked = true;
        break;
    case "Bio3":
        BioRB3.IsChecked = true;
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case...is optional");
        break;
}
```

Also, try doing what Alybaba726 said and use CellContentClick or something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        if(e.ColumnIndex == dgv.Columns["Bio"].Index)
        {
            string bioSelected = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

            switch (bioSelected)
            {
                case "Bio1":
                    BioRB1.IsChecked = true;
                    break;
                case "Bio2":
                    BioRB2.IsChecked = true;
                    break;
                case "Bio3":
                    BioRB3.IsChecked = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case...this is optional");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```